# Qdatastream buffer: incorrect hex output

Tags: python, pyqt

in the framework of pyqt6, I am trying to fill a buffer that will be sent via socket to a peer. My problem is that i am not getting the hex output as i expect.

below is what i have:

```
header = [40, 4602, 2023, 9, 1, 11, 22, 30, 59]
content = [65]
message = header + content

buffer = QByteArray()
data_stream = QDataStream(buffer, QIODevice.OpenModeFlag.WriteOnly)
data_stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream.ByteOrder.BigEndian)

for value in message:
    data_stream.writeInt32(value)

print(f'buffer: {buffer}')
print(f'length: {buffer.length()}')
```

the first element in the list, i.e., the message, it is 40, therefore, i expect something like 0x28 yet, i am getting "("

this is the output of the print:

```
buffer: b'\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x11\xfa\x00\x00\x07\xe7\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00\x00A'
```

any idea how come is that?, why do i get a "("?

thanks

Comment: That's normal and expected. Printable ASCII characters will always be displayed as "text" (i.e. `b'\x28' == b'('` -> `True`).